# How to connect to another IP using NGINX

Tags: nginx, server, ip, lamp

I am wondering how to connect to a different IP in Nginx that is different from localhost.

```
00.000.00.00
root
123456
```

note (the IP address and password indicated above are not realand will be replaced will actual)
Right now, this is what I have in Nginx config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default nginx listens on all interfaces, that would be that `listen 80;` is equivalent to `listen 0.0.0.0:80;`. If you want nginx to listen only on localhost you should write `listen 127.0.0.1:80;` or `listen localhost:80;`, and if you want it to listen on some other interface you could do something like `listen 152.168.0.30:80;`.

On the other hand using the line `server_name  localhost;` you are only accepting request directed to localhost in this block, and no the ones directed to your other IP's. To accept this request you can add `server_name  localhost 152.168.0.30 www.myweb.com;` like a list or you could exclude this config so that the host IP isn't a restriction to accept or not a request.

For more information look in [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Hope it helps!